# how to use C# MSChart to write the trigger mode like oscilloscope?

Tags: c#, mschart

I have a `MSChart` to show the data in time. X Axis is timer controller, Y Axis is Data. I had already written the Y-Div & Y-Offset function. But now I would like to write the trigger mode like an oscilloscope. Trigger mode have

1. Auto mode,
2. Normal mode.

How can I write the code of trigger level line, that up down the line to decide if the data show on `MSChart`?
Thanks!
[image]

Comment: You have several options to show a horizontal line, e.g. a HorizontalLineAnnotation (which can even be made interactively moveable) or a StripLine or as line in Seies of type line or even paint the line... But you should tell us more detailed what effect the trigger should on the chart!